# Check if Oracle jdbc driver is registered

Tags: java, jdbc

I have written a simple code to test if the oracle drivers are already registered.

```
private boolean isDriverRegistered(){
    boolean isRegistered = false;
    Enumeration<Driver> loadedDrivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
    while(loadedDrivers.hasMoreElements()){     
        Driver driver = loadedDrivers.nextElement();
        if (driver instanceof OracleDriver){
            isRegistered = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isRegistered;
}
```

Can some one suggest any other better method to do so?

Comment: What for are you going to perform this check?

Comment: you don't like iterating stuff? even internal implementation of [DriverManager.getDriver](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/sql/DriverManager.java.html) does that, so you shouldn't worry

Comment: @Andrew, I want to check if the driver is already registered if(!isDriverRegistered()){
 DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
}

Comment: `Class.forName()` seems the best approach to me. And it's surely most widely used one.

Comment: @user1731553 A driver has to register itself when it is classloaded, only in exceptional cases (ie when a `Driver` intentionally does not register itself) should you use `DriverManager.registerDriver()` yourself. And with JDBC 4 driver implementations, you don't even need to classload the driver yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try a `Class.forName()` with the specific Oracle driver class name. If it can be loaded, it is surely registered.

Answer (score 1):

I think the iteration is fine, but you could use the acceptsURL method instead of the instanceof check (e.g. to avoid compile time dependency to the Oracle Driver):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html#acceptsURL%28java.lang.String%29